# Parsing key value pairs with values accepting space

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse certificate subject key value pairs and I'm trying to do that with regex.

I have written the following regex to capture key value pairs but I have problems with the last pair that isn't matched:

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=\w+\s*=)
```

Do you have an idea how to capture the last pair for such subject:

```
CN = Some CN to catch SERIALNUMBER = aaaa bbbb, O = SIGNATUR,C=PL
```

I expect to get values for such keys: CN, SERIALNUMBER, O and C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lookahead requires 1+ word chars, 0+ whitespace chars and then a `=` after the value is matched.

You need to add the end of string alternative,

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=\w+\s*=|$)
                                         ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqKtJC/1).

You may also use

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<value>\W*(?:\w(?!\w*\s*=)\W*)*)
```

which is a tiny bit more efficient. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqKtJC/3). Here, `\W*(?:\w(?!\w*\s*=)\W*)*` matches any 0+ non-word chars followed with 0+ repetitions of a word char that is not followed with 0+ word and then whitespace chars and then a `=` and the followed with 0+ non-word chars. Basically, it is an [unroll-the-loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)'ed `.*?(?=\w+\s*=|$)` part of the pattern.